# Customizing JAXB Bindings : difference between typeName and elementName

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, xjc

When generating classes from a xsd file, through the `xjc` tool, a binding file can be used. My question is about name transformation. According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148550) :

```
<nameXmlTransform>
  [ <typeName [ suffix="suffix" ]
              [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <elementName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                 [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <modelGroupName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                    [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <anonymousTypeName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                       [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
```

What is the difference between `elementName` and `typeName` ? The documentation does not give precise explanations on these attributes. The first seems to modify class names is some (conflict ?) situation, the second seems to do the job whatever the situation.

I might be wrong that's why a clear explanation would be welcomed.

Comment: Hi. I saw [what happened yesterday on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1138045/150988), and I posted a meta question, [Bounty-setter can’t comment on bounty question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300197/195817), about it. Feel free to participate. (I’m pinging you here because I don’t know whether I can ping you on [SU].)

Comment: P.S.  Why didn’t you just give a 50 point bounty?  Did you try?  Did the system prevent you from doing that?

Comment: I wanted to go all in on this one, I did not think about the comment issue